# Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence prove that if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}>1$ then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence Which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1. if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}>1$ then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$
> 2. if $a_n$ converges or diverges to infinity then $\sqrt[n]a_n$ converges
> 3. if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}{a_n}= \infty$ then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}>1$
> 4. if $\sqrt[n]a_n$ converges then $a_n$ converges or diverges to infinity

---

I believe the correct answer is $1$ because I found contradicitions to the rest but could not prove the first

for the second statement it is not true because let $
a_n=
\begin{cases}
 2^n&\text{if}\, n _{even}\\
 3^n&\text{if}\, n_{odd}\\
\end{cases}
$
then for all $n$ we get $\lim _\limits {n \to \infty} a_n= \infty $ but
$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}=2$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{2n-1}}=3$ so the limit does not exist

for the third statement let $a_n=n$ then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {a_n}= \infty$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$

and for the fourth statement let $
a_n=
\begin{cases}
 n&\text{if}\, n _{even}\\
 1&\text{if}\, n_{odd}\\
\end{cases}
$
so $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{2n}}=1=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{2n-1}}=1$
but the limit for $a_n$ does not exist because $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {a_{2n}}= \infty$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {a_{2n-1}}=1$

But I could not prove or begin with the correct statement which is the first ( according to what I did it is the correct one)

Thanks for any tips and help!

Comment: For 1., you find $\epsilon>0$ such that $\lim_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1+\epsilon$. Hence $a_n>(1+\epsilon)^n$ for almost all $n$. The right member of the inequality diverges to $\infty$, hence $a_n$ as well.

Comment: if the limit exists and it is $c>1$, then by definition of limit $a_n>(c-\epsilon)^n$ definitively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to L > 1$. Then for $\varepsilon := \frac{L-1}2 > 0$ there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
$$n \ge n_0 \implies \sqrt[n]{a_n} \ge L-\varepsilon = \frac{L+1}2.$$
In particular for all $n \ge n_0$ we have
$$a_n \ge \left(\frac{L+1}2\right)^n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} +\infty$$
because $\frac{L+1}2 > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L=\lim_n \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ Then $L>1$. Fix $1<c<L$. THen for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>c$ for all $n\geq N$. That means that
$$a_n\geq c^n,\qquad n\geq N$$
Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct. Let $c > 1$ be the limit. Fix $\epsilon > 0$, then by definition, there exists $N$ such that $\forall n > N, |\sqrt[n]{a_n} - c| < \epsilon \implies a_n > (c - \epsilon)^n$. In particular, we take $\epsilon = \frac{c - 1}{2}$, then $c' := c - \epsilon > 1$ and

$$
a_n > (c - \epsilon)^n = c'^n \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} \infty
$$

---

For the fourth one, I believe $a_n = 1$ works just as well.